# Session Id Changes Across Subdomains - When Called Via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a domain, **example.com**. On this domain I have two subdomains, **code.example.com** and **www.example.com**.

My php.ini file has the following line in it:
`session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`

If I have a simple PHP page on **code.example.com** that sets a PHP session variable then a page on **www.example.com** can read that session variable.

**code.example.com/test.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["testa"] = "a";
```

**www.example.com/test.php**

```
session_start();
echo("session testa = " . $_SESSION["testa"]);
```

This is proven and works. It correctly echoes, *session testa = a*.

However, if I do the same thing, but this time if I have a page on **www.example.com** that calls **code.example.com/test.php** via AJAX, when I read the session variable on **www.example.com/test.php**, it fails. The session variable does not exist.

I traced this through using Network > Cookies in Development Tools in Firefox. I can confirm that the session ids are indeed different and not being passed correctly when doing this through AJAX.

In my AJAX call I have `crossDomain: true` and in my PHP files I have `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` set.

I am really at a loss.

All the searches that I do say to modify the php.ini file. But, I have done that. Cross-subdomain sessions do work. Just not when called via AJAX.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the '.' in front of the top-level domain name. Also the httprequestobject needs ( bool ) obj.withCredentials = tree; for the object to access cross-domain cookies.

Comment: I tried this and it did not seem to make a difference.